# TikZ drawing lines between nodes and text above/below nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows

I want to draw kind of a protocol flow, where I have two parties, and each send one message to the other one. One arrow should be above the other one, and above both arrows there should be some text. Furthermore, I want to write text both below and above the nodes. Currently, I only have text below. I want that text to be above, and below I want to write two lines of math equations. How can I achieve these with TikZ? Currently, I get the error:

> pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/line' and I am going to
> ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
    arrows,
    calc,
    chains,
    decorations,
    decorations.text,
    decorations.pathmorphing,
    matrix,
    positioning,
    shapes,
    tikzmark
}
\usepackage{tikzpeople}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Protocol View}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=5cm]
% nodes
\node[alice,minimum size=1.5cm] (s) at (0,0) {Alice};
\node[bob,minimum size=1.5cm,right of=s] (r) {Bob};
% paths
\path [line] (r) -- node [text width=2.5cm,midway,above,align=center] {$\hat{\sigma}$} (s);
\path [line] (s) -- node [text width=2.5cm,midway,above,align=center] {$\sigma$} (r);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: have a look at the answer below -- should point u in the right direction

Comment: You haven't define a style for "line". This is what cause your error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
    arrows,
    calc,
    chains,
    decorations,
    decorations.text,
    decorations.pathmorphing,
    matrix,
    positioning,
    shapes,
    tikzmark
}
\usepackage{tikzpeople}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{frame}{Protocol View}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=5cm]
            % nodes
            \node[alice,minimum size=1.5cm, label=90:text] (s) at (0,0) {Alice};
            \node[bob,minimum size=1.5cm,right of=s, label=90:text] (r) {Bob};
            % paths
            \draw [->] (r) -- node [text width=2.5cm,midway,above,align=center] {$\hat{\sigma}$} (s);
            \draw [->] ($(s.east)+(1em,-1em)$) -- node [text width=2.5cm,midway,below,align=center] {$\sigma$} ($(r.west)+(-1em,-1em)$) ;
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```